# Determine the diameter of a circle with constraints

Tags: circles

I would like to solve in analytical way the following problem:

[image: click here to show the image of the problem]

1. I have a circle with diameter D1=70mm
2. I have another circle with diameter D2=Xmm which is my unknown of this problem
3. The center to center distance between the circles is 250mm
4. The length of the "belt" (depicted in blue line color) is always fixed to 800mm

The circle identified by diameter D1 represents the driving pulley.
The circle identified by diameter D2 represents the driven pulley.
The blu line is always tangent to both circles (pulleys) and represents the belt.

Now, when I change the diameter D1, I will obtain another value of diameter D2 and today I have to determine the solution with the help of a parametric CAD drawing.

Is there a way to solve it analytically (for example using an Excell sheet).

Thank you in advance!

Deatil of the winding angle on the driven circle:

[winding angle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEFUq.png)

Edit: the winding angle is the same in both circles:
[detail of the system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uITOn.png)

Comment: There are two cases, when D2 is smaller than D1 and when D2 is larger than D1.. so I'd expect a quadratic equation somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

\begin{align}
|T_tT_2|=|O_1C|
&=
\sqrt{d^2-(r_2-r_1)^2}
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
\phi&=\arcsin\Big(\frac{r_2-r_1}d\Big)
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

Constraint:

\begin{align}
(\tfrac\pi2-\phi)\cdot r_1
+\sqrt{d^2-(r_2-r_1)^2}
+(\tfrac\pi2+\phi)\cdot r_2
&=\tfrac12\,L
\tag{3}\label{3}
,
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\text{or }\qquad
\left(
2\,(r_2-r_1)\arcsin\left(\frac{r_2-r_1}d\right)
-
(L-\pi\,(r_2+r_1)
-2\,\sqrt{d^2-(r_2-r_1)^2})
\right)^2
&=0
\tag{4}\label{4}
.
\end{align}

Unfortunately,
in general, 
given $r_1,d$ and $L$
there is no analytic solution for $r_2$
in \eqref{4}, so we need to use numeric methods.

For example, in Excel, 
you can type the formula \eqref{4}
and use built-in non-linear solver
to minimize it.

For example,
for $r_1=35,\ d=250,\ L=800$
we get $r_2=59.71462$.

As the first approximation to $r_2$
you can try

\begin{align}
r_{2\,(0)}
&=
r_1+\pi\,d-\frac{\pi^3\,d^2}{d\,(\pi^2-2)+L-2\pi\,r_1}
.
\end{align}

For the above example, $r_{2\,(0)}\approx 59.69$,
which is pretty close.

For the numeric approximation
you can use, for example, 
[Halley's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_method)
as a root-finding algorithm:

\begin{align}
r_{2(n+1)}
&=
r_{2(n)}
-
\frac{2\,f(r_{2(n)},r_1,d,L)\,f'(r_{2(n)},r_1,d)}
{2\,f'(r_{2(n)},r_1,d)^2-f(r_{2(n)},r_1,d,L)\,f''(r_{2(n)},r_1,d)}
,
\end{align}

where

\begin{align}
f(r_{2},r_1,d,L)
&=
2\,(r_2-r_1)\,\arcsin\Big(\frac{r_2-r_1}d\Big)
-L+\pi\,(r_2+r_1)+2\,\sqrt{d^2-(r_2-r_1)^2}
,\\
f'(r_{2},r_1,d)
&=
2\,\arcsin\Big(\frac{r_2-r_1}d\Big)+\pi
,\\
f''(r_{2},r_1,d)
&=
\frac 2{\sqrt{d^2-(r_2-r_1)^2}}
.
\end{align}

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\hline
n & r_{2(n)} \\
\hline
0 & 35.0000000000 \\
1 & 59.6915126334 \\
2 & 59.7146200516 \\
3 & 59.7146200510 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

This is a minimal `python` example:

```
from math import *
def f(r2,r1,d,L) : 
  """
  r2 - radius of the driven pulley
  r1 - radius of the driving pulley
   d - the center to center distance between the circles 
   L - length of the belt
  """
  return 2*(r2-r1)*asin((r2-r1)/d)-L+pi*(r2+r1)+2*sqrt(d*d-(r2-r1)**2)
def df(r2,r1,d) : 
  """
  f'(r2)
  """
  return 2*asin((r2-r1)/d)+pi
def ddf(r2,r1,d) : 
  """
  f''(r2)
  """
  return 2/sqrt(d*d-(r2-r1)**2)
def F(r2,r1,d,L) :
  """
  next approximation to r2
  """
  vf=f(r2,r1,d,L)
  vdf=df(r2,r1,d) 
  vddf=ddf(r2,r1,d) 
  return r2-2*vf*vdf/(2*vdf**2-vf*vddf)
def calc_r2(r1,d,L,eps=1e-6) :
  r2o=r1
  r2=F(r2o,r1,d,L)
  while(abs(r2-r2o)>eps) :
    r2o=r2
    r2=F(r2o,r1,d,L)
  return r2

print(calc_r2(35,250,800))
# 59.71462005113761
print(calc_r2(20,250,800))
# 72.03312874960544
print(calc_r2(3,250,800))
# 84.05267790667017
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You are very very accurate.
I created an Excel sheet with the goal seak function, trying to minimize the function (4) to zero. The results are totally matching the CAD drawing, therefore the mission is deemed complete.
Thank you very much for the effort and for the great support!
Best regards!

Comment: @kalo86: You can accept the answer, if it was helpful.

Comment: I clicked on the green flag, is it enough to accept the answer or is there another way to do it? Thank you!

Comment: @kalo86: Yes, that's fine.
And btw, for future reference, you may take a look at 
[this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
to see how to format math on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Hint - Suppose we consider the case that D2 > D1

Now, drop the perpendicular from centre of D1 to the radius connecting tangent point and centre of D2. You will get a right triangle with arm lengths 250,  $\frac{x-70}{2}$

Can you relate the angles of this triangle to the angle subtended by the sectors made by rope contact with each circle? And then use the total length equation to get an equation in x?

EDIT

The entire diagram is symmetric about the line joining the centres

Let $C_1$ be centre of circle 1, $C_2$ be centre of circle 2, and the foot of perpendicular be P. Hence, angle subtended by contact line on small circle is  $2*(90 - \angle PC_1C_2)$

For $C_2$, the angle subtended is $2*(180-\angle PC_2C_1)$

To see this, just extend the line joining the two centres till it intersects the circle. Once you do that, it should not be difficult to relate the angles as above

Comment: Check edit. If still unclear then let me know

Comment: The problem is that the belt is tangent in different locations, therefore there will be a different angle.I added a new detailed picture on the angle at the driven pulley. Thank you for the hint!

Comment: The angles can't be different, unless the string isn't taut?

Comment: Which angles are you talking about?

Comment: Dhanvi Sreenivasan, I updated the first post with a detaied drawing showing the angles between the vertical reference axis and the tangency point between the pully circle and belt arm. This angle is the same in both circles C1 and C2.